# Regex to match mentions and hashtags in Twitter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this JS right here:

```
return text.replace(/@([a-z\d_]+)/ig, '<a
href="?r=site/twitterprofile&q=$1">@$1</a>');
```

It gets all of the Twitter mentions, and outputs the link for each. In this same function, I want to combine this pattern to get all of the hashtags:

```
/\S*#\S+/gi
```

How do I combine these two into one pattern?

Comment: Why are you using `replace`?

Comment: You want only hashtags inside @ mentions? Simply apply them in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the `.replace()` function lets you pass in a *function* to return a replacement string:

```
return text.replace(/([@#])([a-z\d_]+)/ig, function(_, marker, tag) {
  if (marker === "@")
    return '<a href="?r=site/twitterprofile&q=$1">' + tag + '</a>';
  return "Hashtag: " + tag;
});
```

That looks for things that look like either `@` tags or hashtags, and then decides which sort of replacement to return. When you pass a function to `.replace()`, the function is called such that the first argument (ignored in the sample above) is the entire match. The second and subsequent arguments contain the grouped sub-matches, corresponding to `$1`, `$2`, etc when you use a simple string replacement. Thus the first group is the `@` or `#` character, and the second is the matched text.

Answer (score 0):

**regex for match hashtags:**

```
\(#[a-zA-Z\d_-]+)/ig
```

**regex for match mentions:**

```
/(^|)(@[a-zA-Z0-9\d-]+)/ig
```

**regex for URLs:**

```
/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Z09+&@#\/%=~_|])/img
```

---

**`i`, `m`, `g` are regex options**

`i` option means : insensitive => Case insensitive match.
`m` option means : global => Don't return after first match, find all matches.
`g` option means : multi line => ^ and $ match start/end of line.